# How to correctly encode & in xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Im web-requsting an XML document. `Xdocument.Load(stream)` throws an exception because the XML contains `&`, and therefore expects `;` like `&amp;`.

I did read the stream to string and replaced `&` with `&amp;`, but that broke all other correctly encoded special chars like `&oslash;`.

Is there a simple way to encode all disallowed chars in the string before parsing to `XDocument`?

Comment: How do you get the xml? how does it look like?

Comment: It cannot contain `&oslash;`, because this character entity is not defined in XML. You are probably trying to read an HTML file. HTML and XML are not compatible. If you *are* in fact trying to read HTML, you should go with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @L.B I use a c# System.Net WebRequest to an URL. The Xml contains  lots of data and breaks because it contains & in clear text not &amp; and not omitted by CDATA blocks. Eks: <root><node1>My text & his text</node1><node2>This is a special char &aelig;</node2><root>

Comment: @Tomalak I tried to fix it by doing a string Replace("&", "&amp;") That broke all special char like æ ø å. I just asumed that it contained htmlencoded values for these special chars.

Comment: @espvar Again: There *are* no special characters `&oslash;` in XML. They are defined for HTML, not for XML. Even if the source would encode the `&` correctly, the resulting document would still be broken and unparsable. If you cannot fix the source, the HTML Agility Pack is the way to go. It contains a forgiving parser that will be able to produce a document object from broken input.

Comment: @espvar, !! I have an idea, but before that are you fine if your XML data has `<![CDATA[..]` around the TEXT within the XML nodes.. ??

Comment: example: Your data `<foo>some data &oslash;</foo>` if looks like `<foo><![CDATA[some data &oslash;]]></foo>`

Comment: The source does not wrap problem chars with <![CDATA[]]>.

Comment: @espvar! No!! Source need not do that !! You can do it now!! By simple algorithm! just let me know if it is fine!

Comment: step1: By using simple algorithm (not really simple to be honest), by using .net code you can wrap the text that has `&`!! like I showed above! no need to encode! just string replacement will do!

Comment: step2: once it is encoded with CDATA, you can load it as an XML!! you can pass it or store wherever you wish

Comment: step3: while extracting data from XML: extract the CDATA sections separately !! YOU ARE DONE!!

Comment: want to give a shot? If you are fine with this process then I will try otherwise don't wanna waste my effort! I understand that your problem here is loading the string as an XML! Moreover your XML has invalid encoded characters like `&oslash;`!! this kind of data must be treated as CDATA no other way!!

Comment: I m fine with the CDATA wrap:)

Answer (score 0):

Try CDATA Sections in xml

A CDATA section can only be used in places where you could have a text node.

```
<foo><![CDATA[Here is some data including < , > or & etc) ]]></foo>
```

Comment: If I had access to the source i would do this, but I dont:/

Comment: Please refer this and I am happy if it helps you : http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html

Answer (score 0):

This kind of methods are not encouraged!! The reason lies in your question!

(replacing & by `&amp;` turns `&gt;` to `&amp;gt;`)

The better suggestion apart from using regex is modifying your source code which is generating such uncoded XML.

I have come across (.NET) code that use 'string concat' to come up with XML! (Instead one should use XML-DOM)
 If you have an access to modify the source code then better go head with that .. because encoding such half-encoded XML is not promised with perfection!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that i dont have access to the source of the xml. I have alerted the source owner of the problem, but i fear it is gona take som time, and I need a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

@espvar,

This is an input XML:

```
<root><child>nospecialchars</child><specialchild>data&data</specialchild><specialchild2>You.. & I in this beautiful world</specialchild2>data&amp;</root>
```

And the Main function:

```
        string EncodedXML = encodeWithCDATA(XMLInput); //Calling our Custom function

        XmlDocument xdDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xdDoc.LoadXml(EncodedXML); //passed
```

The function encodeWithCDATA():

```
    private string encodeWithCDATA(string stringXML)
    {
        if (stringXML.IndexOf('&') != -1)
        {

            int indexofClosingtag = stringXML.Substring(0, stringXML.IndexOf('&')).LastIndexOf('>');
            int indexofNextOpeningtag = stringXML.Substring(indexofClosingtag).IndexOf('<');

            string CDATAsection = string.Concat("<![CDATA[", stringXML.Substring(indexofClosingtag, indexofNextOpeningtag), "]]>");

            string encodedLeftPart = string.Concat(stringXML.Substring(0, indexofClosingtag+1), CDATAsection);
            string UncodedRightPart = stringXML.Substring(indexofClosingtag+indexofNextOpeningtag);
            return (string.Concat(encodedLeftPart, encodeWithCDATA(UncodedRightPart)));
        }
        else
        {
            return (stringXML);
        }
    }
```

Encoded XML (ie, xdDoc.OuterXml):

```
<root>
  <child>nospecialchars</child>
  <specialchild>
    <![CDATA[>data&data]]>
  </specialchild>
  <specialchild2>
    <![CDATA[>You.. & I in this beautiful world]]>
  </specialchild2>
  <![CDATA[>data&amp;]]>
</root>
```

All I have used is, substring, IndexOf, stringConcat and recursive function call.. Let me know if you don't understand any part of the code.

The sample XML that I have provided possess data in the parent nodes as well, which is kind of HTML property .. ex: `<div>this is <b>bold</b> text</div>..`  and my code takes care of encoding data outside `<b>` tag if they have special character ie, &..

Please note that, I have taken care of encoding '&' only and .. data cannot have chars like '<' or '>' or single-quote or double-quote..

Comment: <![CDATA[> should be <![CDATA[